# UTF-8 issue in Java code

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm getting a string 'ÐÐ°Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð´Ð°ÑÐ' instead of getting 'Календари' in Java code. How can I convert 'ÐÐ°Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð´Ð°ÑÐ' to 'Календари'?

I used

```
 String convert =new String(convert.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8") 
 String convert =new String(convert.getBytes(), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Can you expand the code sample a little bit? Its not clear where the input is coming from. Also not clear if you're reading io, or have a string in memory?

Comment: the first line works for me in my code

Comment: Where is the string coming from to begin with? Why are you using ISO-8859-1, which cannot encode the characters you have shown?

Comment: What are you using to display the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your code is okay.  It appears that your problem is that you need to do a specific character conversion, and maybe your "real" input is not being encoded correctly.  To test, I would do a standard step by step CharSet encoding/decoding, to see where things are breaking.

Your encodings look fine, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

And the following seems to run normally :

```
//i suspect your problem is here - make sure your encoding the string correctly from the byte/char stream. That is, make sure that you want "iso-8859-1" as your input characters. 

Charset charsetE = Charset.forName("iso-8859-1");
CharsetEncoder encoder = charsetE.newEncoder();

//i believe from here to the end will probably stay the same, as per your posted example.
Charset charsetD = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charsetD.newDecoder();

ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(inputString));
CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
final String result = cbuf.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Yes i tried this code also..its working in eclipse.Ath the same time when i run  this code in netbeans the resulting string look like this'???????'

Comment: That could be a jdk issue or a input issue....?  Check with charset.isEncodngSupported

Answer (score 2):

Use the Unicode values instead of string literals. For more information, see:

1. [Russian on-screen keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdru.html) (hover over for Unicode values)
2. And how about a [list of Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters.)?

**Edit -** 
Note that it's important to use an output font that supports displaying Unicode values (e.g. `Arial Unicode MS`).

**Example -**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

final class RussianDisplayDemo extends JFrame 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3843706833781023204L;

    /**
     * Constructs a frame the is initially invisible to display Russian text
     */
    RussianDisplayDemo()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(getRussianButton());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a button with Russian text
     * 
     * @return a button with Russian text
     */
    private final JButton getRussianButton()
    {
        final JButton button = new JButton("\u042da\u043d\u044f\u0442\u043e"); // Russian for "Busy"
        return button;
    }

    public static final void main(final String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public final void run() 
            {
                final RussianDisplayDemo demo = new RussianDisplayDemo();
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]