# java console charset translation

Tags: java

Console input (win), how is the charset convertion working?

Code below, non-ascii chars output garbage - InputStreamReader in the below example doesn't take charset as an argument.

```
BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inp = console.readLine();
System.out.println(inp.toUpperCase());
```

Being os-independent, how does Java solve all different possible charset configurations regarding console prompt input?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, **Java doesn't handle this problem at all**.

It simply assumes that console encoding is the same as the system default encoding. [This assumption is wrong on Windows systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page), therefore Java doesn't provide good solution to perform correct console IO with respect to non-ascii characters on Windows.

Possible solutions are:

- Use `System.console()` introduced in Java 6:

  ```
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(System.console().reader());
  BufferedWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.console().writer(), true);

  out.println(in.readLine().toUpperCase());
  ```

  Note that `System.console()` can return `null` when you program run with redirected IO, for example, in IDE. You need a fallback for this case.
- Specify console encoding explicitly:

  ```
  String consoleEncoding = "...";
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, consoleEncoding));
  BufferedWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.in, consoleEncoding), true);

  out.println(in.readLine().toUpperCase());
  ```

  As far as I know, there are no good ways to determine actual console encoding programmatically without native code.
- Specify console encoding as default encoding using `file.encoding` property, so that the assumption that console IO uses default encoding would be correct:

  ```
  java -Dfile.encoding=... ...
  ```

Answer (score 5):

**1) Practically speaking : how do Character Encodings work, and how you should deal with them :**

Any character stream that is read in is Encoded/Decoded.  Java bundles the encoding/decoding specifics as part of the JDK : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html.  Example : [UTF-8 issue in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612511/utf-8-issue-in-java-code/8612716#8612716).

**2) Your specific question : HOW does the cross-platform JAVA language handle console input which is OS-specific ?**

*The short answer : Although Java byte-code is platform neutral, the JVM is NOT.  That is, the java "System" "in/out/err" streaming functionality is not implemented fully in regular old java !*

When you RUN java, the "System" class, which abstracts the basic notion of a system that the JVM is running in, is loaded.  In this time, it's input/output/error streams are (i.e. the objects you are accessing when you type System.in , System.out, System.err are set up at RUNTIME by the ClassLoader which is responsible for, well ... loading java classes.

In the case of "System", ClassLoading is a sophisticated task, as you imply, because setting up the **System** class (just like setting up the java **Runtime** class) is a lower level JVM implementation issue is OS specific.

**Again, just to be clear : Although the Java LANGUAGE is platform-independent, the JVM for your platform is thus, unlike the Java programming language, an OS specific environment that creates the resources we reference in our code for us at runtime.**

For more understanding : Checkout the actual source code for the System class, its very readable and will give you a better understanding whats going on. In particular, look at the nullInputStream() method :

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/System.java.htm