# Java: Converting UTF 8 to String

Tags: java, utf-8

When I run the following program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    byte str[] = {(byte)0xEC, (byte)0x96, (byte)0xB4};
    String s = new String(str, "UTF-8");
}
```

on Linux and inspect the value of s in jdb, I correctly get:

```
 s = "ì–´"
```

on Windows, I incorrectly get:

```
s = "?"
```

My byte sequence is a valid UTF-8 character in Korean, why would it be producing two very different results?

Comment: How do you "get" the values? Do you print them to console?

Comment: The windows command prompt cannot display UTF8 characters unless you change the codepage using `chcp` and you need to use a font that can display those characters.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616915/java-console-charset-translation

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/330315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It correctly prints "`어`" on my computer (Ubuntu Linux), as described in [*Code Table Korean Hangul*](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/diglib/codetables/9.3.html). Windows command prompt is known to have issues with encoding, don't bother.

Your code is fine.

Comment: My mistake.  The Korean characters were properly displaying in my Emacs text buffer so I naturally assumed that they would display properly in the Emacs shell buffer.  Which as folks pointed out, they do not.

Answer (score 1):

It gives `어` for me. This means your console is probably not configured to display UTF-8 and it is a printing/display problem, rather than a problem with representation.

Answer (score 1):

You get the correct string, it's Windows console that does not display the string correctly.

Here is a [link](http://blog.maurus.be/index.php/2011/03/unicode-windows-console-output-and-java/) to an article that discusses a way to make Java console produce correct Unicode output using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

JDB is displaying the data incorrectly.  The code works the same on both Windows and Linux.  Try running this more definitive test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte str[] = {(byte)0xEC, (byte)0x96, (byte)0xB4};
    String s = new String(str, "UTF-8"); 
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf((int)s.charAt(i)).toString(16));
    }
}
```

This prints out the hex value of every character in the string.  This will correctly print out "c5b4" in both Windows and Linux.