# Getting unicode values from System.in

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have created a `Scanner` that gets input from `System.in` so that I can get input from the console.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

When I do

```
String s = scanner.next();
```

and then input `Слово דבר` in the console, the value of the string becomes `???? ???`.

The console is able to display Unicode characters, but why can't I read them?

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe to assume `System.in` is UTF-8 encoded. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616915/java-console-charset-translation) for some workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

This is because System.in returns text in default encoding (your default encoding is evidently not UTF-8). This should work OK

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.next();
System.out.println(s);
```

And you can read your default encoding from Java

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```