# How to read the character Ā from the user using the System.in.read()?

Tags: java, io, byte

`System.in.read()` can read a byte and returns it as `int`(ranging from 0-255) . How do I get the Unicode characters from the user whose integer values are greater than 255?

Edit: I know that this could be solved using `Reader`, I just want to know if `System.in.read()` simply **CAN NOT** read a character(>255) that takes more than a byte to store( because `System.in.read()` can read only up to a byte)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting unicode values from System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050123/getting-unicode-values-from-system-in)

Comment: Use a Reader (or a Scanner) to read characters. Not a stream.

Comment: You answered your own question. If a character is encoded as two bytes, there is no way System.in.read() returns these two bytes, since it only returns one byte. A Reader will simply read as many bytes needed from System.in in order to be able to decode the byte(s) to characters.

Answer (score 0):

refer to:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

"...The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255..."

System.in.read() simply CAN NOT read a character greater than 255.

Comment: So, the only solution is to use a Reader?

Comment: Yes, the read() method of Reader. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read()

Answer (score -1):

[image]well I have just tested the `System.in.read()` method while using the letter "ת" as an input and it returned 260, so appearantly it can return (or read) characters with bit code that is greater than 255.

```
          public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           System.out.print("Enter something: ");
           int s = System.in.read();
           System.out.print('\n' + s);
           }
```

[image]

It appears that maybe each computer / machine has it's own char-to-int (which is greater than 255) thing, so each computer may show you a different result for the letter ת that I inputed.

Comment: It can't possibly return a value bigger than 255. A byte can't be bigger than 255. The javadoc clearly says that a byte is returned, whose value is in the range 0 to 255. Or -1 if the end of the stream is reached. And of course, when I try your code (MacOS), 225 is being printed.

Comment: well then try any other special letter on your mac. it says that it read 260 from what I inputed. check out the edit.

Comment: and by the way, System.in.read() does not return a byte. it returns an integer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--: Reads the next **byte** of data from the input stream. The value **byte** is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no **byte** is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned

Comment: then explain how I got 260.

Comment: I'd guess that it has to to with the output being intermingled with Maven output using ANSI codes for colors, etc.

Comment: well then, that's pretty much the answer for the question... System.in.read() can read characters greater than byte code 255. It was just proved.

Comment: [link]http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0100 according to this site, the integer value for the character that u entered "ת" is 1514. "Ą" this is the character whose int value is 260

Comment: so basicly, each machine has it's own char-to-int mechanics and every computer makes it different... so isn't my answer the correct one?