# How do I get an input in java without using strings?

Tags: java

So i am trying to implement a very simple program.

i want to set bobi to a variable but without using strings. I am thinking I can do it using just char.

this is what i have so far

```
System.out.println("Please Enter a four letter name");
char n =
char a = 
char m = 
char e =
System.out.print("His name is ");
System.out.print(n);
System.out.print(a);
System.out.print(m);
System.out.print(e);
```

with the program i have  it is

```
your program: Enter four letter name:
user: b
user: o
user: b
user: i
```

I want to be able to enter in one input
so its like this

```
 program: Enter four letter name:
 user: bobi
```

or is there a better way to approach

Comment: A variable of what type?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) System.out.print((char)System.in.read());`

Comment: Why?  I see no benefit to it.

Comment: I'm curious why don't you want to use string?

Comment: It's true that reading a String will probably be simpler.

Comment: is it ok to store it into a string then convert it ?

Comment: its for an assignment at school.

Comment: Just get a string and make sure it's length is 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System.in` stream is the key here. You need to read each `byte` coming in and run it through an `explicit cast` to a `char`.

```
char n = (char)System.in.read();
char a = (char)System.in.read();

// And so on.
```

**Reading Material so you understand this**

- Using the System.in functionality in Java. Click [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html).
- A lesson in Explicit Casts. Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to read raw data from `System.in`:

```
char[] name = new char[4];
try {
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = (char)System.in.read()) != '\n') {
        if(i < name.length)
            name[i++] = c;
    }
} catch(IOException ioe) {}
```

There's a couple of notes:

- `System.in` is terminated by a new line character (from user pressing 'enter') unlike other streams which are null or -1 terminated.
- `System.in` should be compatible with UTF-8. It's probably the same as the system property `file.encoding`. I can't find an official source that says so but in any case you can just cast it to a char. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616915/java-console-charset-translation) seems to suggest compatibility would be a problem for other readers as well.

Note that this may not be simpler. Compare with using `Scanner`:

```
String line = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
if(line.length() > 4)
    line = line.substring(0, 4);
```

And for both cases, you cannot control what the user enters except after they've entered it. You ask for a 4-character name but they can enter "Joe Brown" and they can enter nothing.